# Matrix Configuration

Tags: matrices

I am wanting to write a matrix that looks like this:
[image]

My latex code is:

```
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
    I_{k} & m^T \\
    \hline
    P
\end{array}\right)
```

which is not giving me exactly what I need. Any tips?

Comment: Welcome on TeX StackExchange! You should have a look on the package `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many options to do it. e.g. `\usepackage{multicol}` and `\usepackage{multirow}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
Some text before, $\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
    \multirow{3}{*}{$I_k$} & m_1    \\
                           & \vdots \\
                           & m_k    \\
                           \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{P}
\end{array}\right)$, Some text after
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by F. Pantigny in the comments, it could be done with [nicematrix](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix). I wanted to try this package for a long time, so I'll use this post as an excuse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
Some text before, 
$\begin{pNiceArray}{c|c}[margin]
    \Block{3-1}{I_k} & m_1 \\
    & \Vdots \\
    & m_k \\
    \hline
    \Block{1-2}{P}
\end{pNiceArray}$, Some text after
\end{document}
```

The `\Block{height-width}{Text}` create a block with `Text` centered.

The `[margin]` optional argument created space between the parenthesis and the hline. If you remove it, the hline will touch the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceArray}{c|c}[margin=1pt]
\Block{3-1}{I_k} & m_1 \\
                 & \vdots \\
                 & m_k \\
\hline
\Block{1-2}{P}
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that employs one `array` and one `matrix` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' environment
\begin{document}
\[
- % indicator of math axis
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
    I_{k} & 
    \begin{matrix} m_1 \\ \vdots \\ m_k \end{matrix} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{P}
\end{array}
\right)
- % indicator of math axis
\]
\end{document}
```